# Unable to map SharePoint Online library

Tags: sharepoint, office365, webdav, sharepoint-online

I am struggling to map SharePoint Online libraries to my local machine (Windows 10 64 bit). When I try to map the location via 'Map a Network Location' menu from Windows Explorer, I get the following error: 'The folder you entered does not appear to be valid. Please try another'

I am specifying the path as https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/example/library

Few points:

1. The machine I am trying to map on is an AWS Workspace
2. I am easily able to map these libraries on my local machine
3. I have installed all the system updates

Answer (score 0):

There is a free PowerShell script available here http://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/onedrivemapper/ to map drives to SharePoint Online. You may find better success with the script as it performs a number of checks and environmental changes automatically. A guide and FAQ is also available from the same link.

The PowerShell/scripting approach does rely on automating Internet Explorer to create the cookies which can be unreliable at times. If you would consider a commercial solution for drive mapping then take a look at Zee Drive which authenticates to SharePoint Online directly, maps the drives permanently and does a whole lot more such as local caching: [Reliably map network drives to OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Online with Zee Drive](http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/)

Disclosure: Zee Drive is a tool my company develops

Answer (score 0):

Use OneDrive for Business Sync Client which comes with your office installation. You can map any SharePoint document library locally and is also recommended for larger files and larger lists.

Assuming you have Office 2013 or 2016, you can search for "OneDrive" and you will see the OneDrive for Business app.